# Dart - Encode and decode base64 string

Tags: dart

How to native convert *string* -> *base64* and *base64* -> *string*

I'm find only this [bytes to base64string](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-crypto-base64)

would like this:

```dart
String Base64String.encode();
String Base64String.decode();
```

or ported from another language is easier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [BASE64 codec](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-convert/BASE64-constant.html) (renamed `base64` in Dart 2) and the [LATIN1 codec](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-convert/LATIN1-constant.html) (renamed `latin1` in Dart 2) from convert library.

```dart
var stringToEncode = 'Dart is awesome';

// encoding

var bytesInLatin1 = LATIN1.encode(stringToEncode);
// [68, 97, 114, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 119, 101, 115, 111, 109, 101]

var base64encoded = BASE64.encode(bytesInLatin1);
// RGFydCBpcyBhd2Vzb21l

// decoding

var bytesInLatin1_decoded = BASE64.decode(base64encoded);
// [68, 97, 114, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 119, 101, 115, 111, 109, 101]

var initialValue = LATIN1.decode(bytesInLatin1_decoded);
// Dart is awesome
```

If you always use `LATIN1` to generate the encoded String you can avoid the 2 convert calls by creating a codec to directly convert a String to/from an encoded String.

```dart
var codec = LATIN1.fuse(BASE64);

print(codec.encode('Dart is awesome'));
// RGFydCBpcyBhd2Vzb21l

print(codec.decode('RGFydCBpcyBhd2Vzb21l'));
// Dart is awesome
```

Comment: this answer from 2013 is now deprecated

Answer (score 14):

As of 0.9.2 of the `crypto` package

> `CryptoUtils` is deprecated. Use the `Base64` APIs in `dart:convert` and the hex APIs in the `convert` package instead.

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show utf8, base64;

main() {
  final str = 'https://dartpad.dartlang.org/';

  final encoded = base64.encode(UTF8.encode(str));
  print('base64: $encoded');

  final str2 = utf8.decode(base64.decode(encoded));
  print(str2);
  print(str == str2);
}
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/460627beb8fe2c4e00b05e24e0cd22ed)

Answer (score 7):

I would comment on Günter's April 10th, 2016, post, but I don't have the reputation.  As he says, you should use the `dart:convert` library, now.  You have to combine a couple of codecs to get a utf8 string out of a base64 string and vice-versa. [This article](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/converters-and-codecs) says that [fusing your codecs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-convert/Codec/fuse.html) is faster.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var base64 = 'QXdlc29tZSE=';
  var utf8 = 'Awesome!';

  // Combining the codecs
  print(utf8 == UTF8.decode(BASE64.decode(base64)));
  print(base64 == BASE64.encode(UTF8.encode(utf8)));
  // Output:
  // true
  // true

  // Fusing is faster, and you don't have to worry about reversing your codecs
  print(utf8 == UTF8.fuse(BASE64).decode(base64));
  print(base64 == UTF8.fuse(BASE64).encode(utf8));
  // Output:
  // true
  // true
}
```

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5c0e1cfb6d1d640cdc902fe57a2a687d

Comment: Why isn't this built into dart:convert library?!

Comment: It's not built into the convert library because that library has a lot of different converters, encoders and codecs, and it would be overkill to have all the combinations of these as well. The `fuse` operation is there so you can make the combinations you neeed yourself.

Comment: this does not work for me, my string is binary, I can't do a utf8 decode on it

Comment: I created this if you are using DartPad and having problems to render an app with the long string variable https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/1342#issuecomment-862016884

Answer (score 4):

Here is a example of encoding/decoding in dart:

main.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  // encode
  var str = "Hello world";
  var bytes = utf8.encode(str);
  var base64Str = base64.encode(bytes);
  print(base64Str);

  // decode
  var decoded_bytes = base64.decode(base64Str);
  var decoded_str = utf8.decode(decoded_bytes);
  print(decoded_str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a class dart.io -> base64.dart, modified it a bit, and there you are

how to use:

```dart
var somestring = 'Hello dart!';

var base64string = Base64String.encode( somestring );
var mystring = Base64String.decode( base64string );
```

[source on pastbin.com](http://pastebin.com/0FBhjnnG)

[source on gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/ahiipsa/4754533)