# How to decode the image which is a base64 string, in Dart?

Tags: image, png, base64, dart

I tried to get the image from clipboard when I press `ctrl+v` on a page, with the code from [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Buildstarted/4577472), which will `console.log` the image content it gets.

I found the image content is a long base64 string with a special prefix:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

How to decode it to binary? I tried to remove the prefix `data:image/png;base64,` and use a base64 library to decode the rest into binary, and save it to a `image.png` file. But the file can't be displayed, with `invalid format` error.

But if I paste the whole string to http://base64online.org/decode/, it can play the image as well.

The base64 library I used is https://github.com/wstrange/base64, and my code is:

```dart
import 'package:base64_codec/base64_codec.dart';

var body = /* the long str above */;

var prefix = "data:image/png;base64,";
var bStr = body.substring(prefix.length);
var bs = Base64Codec.codec.decodeList(bStr.codeUnits);
var file = new File("image.png");
file.writeAsBytesSync(bs);
```

I don't know where is wrong :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `crypto` package from the Dart SDK.  This creates an image.png that opens fine (I believe it's this image... [image])

```dart
library foo;

import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  var body = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh... snip"; 
  var prefix = "data:image/png;base64,";
  var bStr = body.substring(prefix.length);
  var bytes = CryptoUtils.base64StringToBytes(bStr); // using CryptoUtils from Dart SDK
  var file = new File("image.png");
  file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes);
}
```

You'll need to add `crypto` to your `pubspec.yaml` :

```
dependencies:
  crypto: any
```

The library linked at https://github.com/wstrange/base64, also notes in the README:

> Deprecated
>
> Note: The Dart SDK now includes a Base64 codec with url safe options. Unless you need streaming support, you should use the SDK methods as they are slightly faster.
>
> See CryptoUtils

See also [How to native convert string -> base64 and base64 -> string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755421/how-to-native-convert-string-base64-and-base64-string/36529793#36529793)

Answer (score 4):

Decoding as a string and then writing the bytes works:

```dart
var prefix = "data:image/png;base64,";
var bStr = body.substring(prefix.length);
var bs = Base64Codec.codec.decodeString(bStr);
var file = new File("image.png");
file.writeAsBytesSync(bs.codeUnits);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and I know where is my mistake now. But since Chris's answer is a better solution, so I accept his. Thanks again ~

Comment: just a small correction `body.substring(prefix.length)` would be `body.substring(prefix.length+1)`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final result = base64Decode(stringValue);
```

Comment: yep, and if you want to show the image right away in Flutter you may simply write: `Image.memory(result)` and you're good.