# dart:html - convert String from HttpRequest to List<int>

Tags: dart, archive

I want to use dart:archive on the server and client side to compress the bandwidth used in my web app.

At the moment I read my uncompressed data as a JSON objects with file sizes up to 360 MB, compressed they are about 1/8 of the size.

My Problem:

If I do a HttpRequest I get the data as a String, but I need the data as a List of Bytes to encode it via archive.

It is may a silly question but it already cost me a bunch of hours.

Thanks and cheers from Germany
Felix

Answer (score 2):

For HTTP you usually want it as base64 encoded string ([How to native convert string -> base64 and base64 -> string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755421/how-to-native-convert-string-base64-and-base64-string))

To get the string as bytes this might help

```
List<int> bytes = 'abc'.codeunits;
```

but I'm not sure what you mean by "List of Bytes"