# Flutter: send raw file to google speech api

Tags: audio, dart, speech-recognition, flutter

I'm trying to send a raw file to the google speech api but I don't know how to load the raw file in order to put it into the RecognitionAudio json, any ideas?

This is the code I have right now:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/speech/v1.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

void main() {

  clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _SCOPES).then((http_client) async {
    var speech = new SpeechApi(http_client);
    RecognizeRequest r = new RecognizeRequest();

    String content = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/res/audio.raw');

RecognitionAudio audio = new RecognitionAudio.fromJson({ 'content': content});
    r.audio = audio;
    RecognitionConfig config = new RecognitionConfig.fromJson({
      'languageCode' : 'en-US',
      'encoding' : 'LINEAR16',
      'sampleRateHertz' : 44100,
    });
    r.config = config;
    speech.speech.recognize(r).then((results) {
      for (var result in results.results) {
        print(result.toString());
      }
    });

  });
}
```

and on the pubspec.yaml I've added

```
assets:
    - assets/res/audio.raw
```

And this is the error in the console
E/flutter ( 3740): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_init.cc(167)] Isolate

```
(169749064) 'flutter_assets:_spawn()' exited with an error
E/flutter ( 3740): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 3740): FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0xff (at offset 1)
E/flutter ( 3740): #0      _Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:574)
E/flutter ( 3740): #1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:350)
E/flutter ( 3740): #2      Utf8Codec.decode (dart:convert/utf.dart:72)
E/flutter ( 3740): #3      CachingAssetBundle._utf8decode (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:172)
E/flutter ( 3740): #4      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:94)
E/flutter ( 3740): #5      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:168)
E/flutter ( 3740): #6      _spawn (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:91)
E/flutter ( 3740): #7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:282)
E/flutter ( 3740): #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
E/flutter ( 3740): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 3740): DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: RecognitionAudio not set.)
E/flutter ( 3740): #0      _validateResponse.<anonymous closure> (package:_discoveryapis_commons/src/clients.dart:880)
E/flutter ( 3740): #1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1381)
E/flutter ( 3740): #2      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129)
E/flutter ( 3740): #3      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:633)
E/flutter ( 3740): #4      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:662)
E/flutter ( 3740): #5      _Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:467)
E/flutter ( 3740): #6      _cancelAndValue (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:63)
E/flutter ( 3740): #7      Stream.first.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:1158)
E/flutter ( 3740): #8      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1316)
E/flutter ( 3740): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:330)
E/flutter ( 3740): #10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:257)
E/flutter ( 3740): #11     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68)
E/flutter ( 3740): #12     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15)
E/flutter ( 3740): #13     _JsonStringDecoderSink.close (dart:convert-patch/dart:convert/convert_patch.dart:1459)
E/flutter ( 3740): #14     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:94)
E/flutter ( 3740): #15     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141)
E/flutter ( 3740): #16     _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1304)
E/flutter ( 3740): #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:383)
E/flutter ( 3740): #18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:393)
E/flutter ( 3740): #19     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:277)
E/flutter ( 3740): #20     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:96)
E/flutter ( 3740): #21     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:23)
E/flutter ( 3740): #22     _StringAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:281)
E/flutter ( 3740): #23     _Utf8ConversionSink.close (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:336)
E/flutter ( 3740): #24     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:94)
E/flutter ( 3740): #25     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141)
E/flutter ( 3740): #26     _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1304)
E/flutter ( 3740): #27     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:383)
E/flutter ( 3740): #28     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:393)
E/flutter ( 3740): #29     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:277)
E/flutter ( 3740): #30     _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:106)
E/flutter ( 3740): #31     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:172)
E/flutter ( 3740): #32     _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1304)
E/flutter ( 3740): #33     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:383)
E/flutter ( 3740): #34     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:393)
E/flutter ( 3740): #35     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:277)
E/flutter ( 3740): #36     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:96)
E/flutter ( 3740): #37     _EventSinkWrapper.close (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:23)
E/flutter ( 3740): #38     _ByteAdapterSink.close (dart:convert/byte_conversion.dart:70)
E/flutter ( 3740): #39     _FilterSink.close (dart:io/data_transformer.dart:604)
E/flutter ( 3740): #40     _ConverterStreamEventSink.close (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:94)
E/flutter ( 3740): #41     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:141)
E/flutter ( 3740): #42     _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1304)
E/flutter ( 3740): #43     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:383)
E/flutter ( 3740): #44     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:393)
E/flutter ( 3740): #45     _BufferingStreamSubscription._close (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:277)
E/flutter ( 3740): #46     _ForwardingStream._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:106)
E/flutter ( 3740): #47     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleDone (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:172)
E/flutter ( 3740): #48     _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1304)
E/flutter ( 3740): #49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:383)
E/flutter ( 3740): #50     _BufferingStreamSubscrip
```

I guess the way I load the content is wrong

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @JonahWilliams  I've updated the question with the error

Comment: I guess you need to base64-encode the raw content first https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/base64-encoding See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755421/how-to-native-convert-string-base64-and-base64-string