# AngularDart upload file convert to base64 string

Tags: angular-dart

I am using AngularDart, Angular 5 and Dart 2.  I have a file input with a change action.

```
<input #inp type="file" id="upload_image" accept="image/*" (change)="handleUpload($event)">
```

This is my handleUpload.

```
Future<void> handleUpload(html.Event e) async {
    e.preventDefault();
    picfile = (e.target as html.FileUploadInputElement).files[0];

}
```

I want to be able to take the html.File object and convert it to an io.File object so that I can base64 encode it and pass it in my JSON to my server. I do something similar in my Flutter app.  Not sure what I am missing, but nothing seems to get the html.File object to be an io.File object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `io.File` in the browser. That exists only for server/console/mobile apps, you can still read the bytes to encode them.

Comment: Thanks, any guidance on how to do that, have not found any way to get it to a base64 String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'dart:html';
...

var blob = e.target as html.FileUploadInputElement).files[0];
var reader = new FileReader()..readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
await reader.onLoadEnd.first;
List<int> /* or Uint8List */ result = reader.result;
print(result);
```

Here you should be able to base64 encode (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36529793/217408)

Comment: I print my blob.name it shows I have a filename that I chose, however when I print result it shows null, and give nullError on encode.  Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: That did it, Thanks

Comment: Yes it did, I marked it yesterday, bit did not take.