# Flutter Base64 Encoded String Is Incomplete

Tags: android, dart, flutter, base64, encode

I'm trying to convert an image byte to base64 encoded string, this operation is successfull but when i print out the encoded string i get the ff:

`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`

An encoded string is supposed to be way more than the characters above. Now when i try to view this by appending `data:image/jpeg;base64`, to the begin of the encoded string, nothing gets displayed.

Is flutter cutting the string in the console or what and if yes then how do i get the complete encoded string.

Comment: Perhaps you are receiving a stream and only encode the first `List<int>` chunk while there are more on the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me base64 is not showing completely. if that the case,
`print()` and `debugPrint()` both are used for logging in the console. If you are use `print()` and output is too much at once, then Android sometimes discards some log lines. To avoid this, use `debugPrint()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert it to Bytes if you're trying to send it to the backend. This will give you the long string you're looking for ;)

```
var params = {
      "image_file": base64Encode(_selectedImage.readAsBytesSync()),
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to native convert string -> base64 and base64 -> string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755421/how-to-native-convert-string-base64-and-base64-string) shows how to base64-encode

Dart also provides constructors on the `Uri` class to get a data URL

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Uri/Uri.dataFromBytes.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Uri/Uri.dataFromString.html

where the former does the base64-encoding for you and the later takes an already encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the debug output windows is truncating it since it's too long. Please make sure on API side whether you take it completely or not.

Answer (score -2):

here is my code

```
static Future<Response> upload64(File file) 
    List<int> imageBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);

    String fileName = path.basename(file.path);

    var body = {"fileName": fileName, "base64": base64Image};
    print("http.upload >> " + body.toString());

  }
```